# Pinch Zoom In/Out Google Map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Flutter version : 3.0.2
Dart Version : 2.17.3

package :
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8

Sample Code of GoogleMap Widget:

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;


Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        GoogleMap(
                                          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                            target: LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
                                            zoom: 18,
                                          ),
                                          minMaxZoomPreference:
                                          MinMaxZoomPreference(8, 19),
                                          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                                          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                                          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                                          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                                          rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
                                          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                                          myLocationEnabled: true,
                                          mapType: MapType.normal,
                                          compassEnabled: false,
                                          onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                                          onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
                                          onCameraIdle: onCameraIdle,
                                          gestureRecognizers: Set()
                                            ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(
                                                () => PanGestureRecognizer())),
                                        ),
                                        Center(
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width: width * 0.15,
                                                height: width * 0.05,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    border: Border.all(
                                                        width: 2,
                                                        color: Colors.black),
                                                    shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.green,
                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                width: width * 0.006,
                                                height: height * 0.025,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        new BorderRadius.only(
                                                      bottomLeft:
                                                          const Radius.circular(
                                                              5.0),
                                                      bottomRight:
                                                          const Radius.circular(
                                                              5.0),
                                                    ),
                                                    color: Colors.black),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 30,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
]),

_onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
 _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
      _googleMapController = controller;
}

onCameraMove(){
print("On Camera Move method");}


onCameraIdle(){
print("On Camera Idle method");}
```

Issue : When trying to pinch zoom in or out the google map, its calling onCameraMove method and onCameraIdle method and zooming in or out is not based on the current location.

So, how to stop calling onCameraMove method and onCameraIdle method while we zoom in/out google map.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the provided snippet here is the working snippet:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MarkerMapWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();

  final ValueNotifier<CameraPosition> currentCameraPosition = ValueNotifier(
      const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946), zoom: 18));

  MarkerMapWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
  }

  onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    print("On Camera Move method $position");

    currentCameraPosition.value = position;
  }

  onCameraIdle() {
    print("On Camera Idle method");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ValueListenableBuilder<CameraPosition>(
      valueListenable: currentCameraPosition,
      builder: (BuildContext context, CameraPosition value, Widget? child) {
        return GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: currentCameraPosition.value,
          minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(8, 19),
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
          rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          compassEnabled: false,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
          onCameraIdle: onCameraIdle,
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
          markers: {
            /// instead of using the centralized widget, use the Marker widget
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(LatLng(currentCameraPosition.value.target.latitude, currentCameraPosition.value.target.longitude).toString()),
              position: LatLng(currentCameraPosition.value.target.latitude, currentCameraPosition.value.target.longitude),
              visible: true,
              draggable: true,
              /// you can change Marker color using the [BitmapDescriptor] blow.
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan),
            )
          },
        );
      });
}
```

If there is anything is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for your comment but while zooming in / out, its not based on the current position. Its taking the position coming from onCameraMove method and map moves vertical or horizontal

Comment: the cause of moving vertical and horizontal is the use of the Stack and Center widgets, that produce the centralized widget which you mean to display a marker!


I'm going to update my answer with the correct way to display a Marker on Map

Comment: @Sharath now you can check the answer again!

Comment: thanks for comment again, but still google map movers vertically or horizontally while zoom in / out. But want i want is while zoom in / out google map it should not call onCameraMove method and onCameraIdle method

Comment: Do you want to keep the marker fixed on the Map?

Comment: Yeah, but only during zoom in/out google map

Comment: Did you try to comment on this line?

'''currentCameraPosition.value = position;'''

Comment: yeah.. but till google map is moving vertically or horizontally while zooming in/out

Comment: now you can disable map moving by updating onCameraMove to


    onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
        print("On Camera Move method $position");
        /// to keep marker fixed at the predifined position comment the following line
        /// And remember that on Map zoom in/out every single point moves to zoom in/out
        //  currentCameraPosition.value = position;

        /// to keep your position in center of the screen
        /// and prevent Map from moving
mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(currentCameraPosition.value.target));
      }

Comment: is there is any way to stop onCameraMove and onCameraIdle method while zoom in/zoom out, But it should trigger onCameraMove and onCameraIdle method while vertical or horizontal drag

Comment: for now you can prevent map zooming by:


mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(currentCameraPosition.value.target));